# Managing apple firewall over command line from sandboxed macos application

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, appstore-sandbox

I am new at macos development and I am trying to manage firewall from another macos application. I am trying to develop the application on XCode with swift.

I found out that the firewall can be managed over the command line. For instance following command lists apps which are configured in the firewall.

```
/usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --listapps
```

When sandbox is disabled, it works fine, it returns apps just like running it in the terminal. But after enabling sandbox on xcode it returns:

```
["/bin/sh: /usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw: Operation not permitted"]
```

I checked some capabilities and entitlements on documents. I found enabling scripting other apps at [apple's documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html) but I am not sure if this is what I am looking for.

Is there any way to do this while sandbox is enabled?

Comment: If you know that your application is sandboxed, then why do you access that path without user's permission in the first place?

Comment: I should have written that bold "I am new at macos development" :). I know if I don't develop sandboxed application, I can't send it to mac app store. That's why, I am trying to do so. I don't know which permission should I request in order to accomplish this.

Comment: Hi @Moritz thanks for comment. Is there something like custom entitlement which can be obtained by contacting apple?